# Why won't my function work with parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I'm trying to make a typewriter effect for a web project, I tried making my own, which had parameters, and it didn't work for some reason. I found someone elses typewriter and tried to edit it to understand it better, but it didn't work with parameters.The original code used variables outside of the function that worked fine, but variables failed.

Ive tried editing the functions in small ways that shouldnt matter, but it all fails in the end.

```
//The Working Function
var i = 0;
var txt = "Old McDonald Had a farm";
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
typeWriter();




// The edited function that failed
var i = 0;
var text = "Old McDonald Had a farm";
var spe = 50;

function typeWriter(txt, spe) {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
typeWriter(text, spe);
```

The edited code only outputs the first character than stops, I want it to do all of them. My web text editor doesn't like jQuery so finding an actual error is complicated

Comment: You use `setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);` yet your parameter is named `spe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you meant to change the function signature to `typewriter(txt, speed)` which would fix the issue raised in my comment.

The second problem is that you do not pass any parameters to the function when you call it for a second time. This means that `txt` is `undefined` & `txt.length` results in an error.

The below could will allow you to pass the parameters to the function using `setTimeout`:

```
function typeWriter(txt, speed) {
    if (i < txt.length) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(function() { typeWriter(txt, speed); }, speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I only screwed up the signature on here, but I can't beleive I forgot to add parameters in setTimeout .

Comment: I thought that may have been the case :-) Sometimes all it takes is a second set of eyes. As for finding the error, take a look at the page inspector of your browser (typically by pressing F12). It's very useful for debugging clientside.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is not correct, change function typeWriter(txt, spe) to function typeWriter(txt, speed).